# BASH extract value after string in variable Not file

Tags: bash, awk, extract

I've found a weird problem I cannot resolve.

I need to extract some values in a variable, these values are after a string.

The name of the variable in this example is: DSLSTATE

Here an example of the value in it:

```
NewEnable 1
NewStatus Up
NewDataPath Fast
NewUpstreamCurrRate 21598
NewDownstreamCurrRate 170788
NewUpstreamMaxRate 25692
NewDownstreamMaxRate 170788
NewUpstreamNoiseMargin 90
NewDownstreamNoiseMargin 60
NewUpstreamAttenuation 150
NewDownstreamAttenuation 170
NewATURVendor 41564d00
NewATURCountry 0400
NewUpstreamPower 486
NewDownstreamPower 514
```

This is not an array.

To extract the value I want I make:

```
ATTUPSTREAM=$(echo "$DSLTATE" | awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "NewUpstreamAttenuation") print $(I+1)}')
```

In this example the value should be 150 but it's always empty.

The weird thing is that I can extract all the values from the same variable with the same command with the exception of the one of the example.
If I execute the same command on terminal it works, in the script is not working.

Here an extract of the script:

```
UPSTREAM=$(echo $DSLSTATE | awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "NewUpstreamCurrRate") print $(I+1)}')
DOWNSTREAM=$(echo $DSLSTATE | awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "NewDownstreamCurrRate") print $(I+1)}')
ATTUPSTREAM=$(echo $DSLTATE | awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "NewUpstreamAttenuation") print $(I+1)}')
ATTDOWNSTREAM=$(echo $DSLSTATE | awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "NewDownstreamAttenuation") print $(I+1)}')
SNRUPSTREAM=$(echo $DSLSTATE | awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "NewUpstreamNoiseMargin") print $(I+1)}')
SNRDOWNSTREAM=$(echo $DSLSTATE | awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "NewDownstreamNoiseMargin") print $(I+1)}')
```

These are the results:

```
ATTUPSTREAM=
ATTDOWNSTREAM=170
SNRUPSTREAM=40
SNRDOWNSTREAM=50
```

Maybe there is some strange character in the DSLSTATE variable in the spacing between the values?

Hoping someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Why don't you just do `ATTUPSTREAM=$(awk '/NewUpstreamAttenuation/{print $2}' <<< $DSLTATE)`? This will work for all the other values as well if you replace the search string with the respective one.

Comment: Don't use all upper case names for awk or non-exported shell variables to avoid clashing with builtin variables and other reasons, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization for the shell issues.

Comment: It was a typo in my comment.

Comment: accdias that typo is in the OPs code too - I strongly suspect @rowboat nailed the issue.

Comment: Oh! Good catch!

Comment: Thank you all guys and thank you all for the answers! My mistake here, @rowboat you are right and that is the error now it works! That is the result of my poor coding as EdMorton pointed out

Comment: @EdMorton, since you are the master of shell scripting around here (and I really mean it), do you have any comments about my suggestion in my comment above? Your opinion is always really appreciated.

Comment: @accdias I'm hardly the master of shell scripting but here's my feedback FWIW - it's using a non-portable stringizing construct `<<<` and the OP hasn't told us which shell they''re using so that may not work for them, and it'd fail if a tag was part of another tag, e.g. imagine you had both `NewUpstreamAttenuation` and `NewUpstreamAttenuationMax` in the input - that script would print both values, and (probably less likely) if any of the tags contained a regexp metachar, e.g. `The.Max`, then  you'd need to make sure to escape them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use all upper case names for awk or non-exported shell variables to avoid clashing with builtin variables and other reasons, e.g. see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for the shell issues.
2. You don't need to loop looking for a tag (name) when the input is
   always in tag-value pairs.
3. When you have common code put it
   in a function, don't repeat it multiple times - for all we know
   there could be a control char or other issue in the code for that
   one tags value.

Start by changing your code to use a simple lookup function:

```
$ tag2val() { echo "$DSLSTATE" | awk -v tag="$1" '$1==tag { print $2 }'; }

$ tag2val NewDataPath
Fast

$ tag2val NewUpstreamAttenuation
150
```

and then let us know if you still have a problem. If you do then edit your question to show the output of `echo "$DSLSTATE" | cat -Ev`.

Comment: Hi and thanks you are right for my poor coding here...multiple repetitive code is a bad attitude I will change the code.

Comment: I still have trouble even with the functions with the print $2 part of the awk. It seems that there is some difference between variables ...That is the main reason I used the awk with the cycle in the first place. The main problem is when echo consider the value as a one only row and when a list

Comment: `echo` doesn't do that. Either there are no newlines in your variable or, more likely given  the code in your question, you're removing the double quotes from `echo "$DSLSTATE"` and so, among other things, asking the shell to pass every string of non-blanks in `$DSLSTATE` to `echo` as separate arguments instead of one single argument. It's extremely important to understand quoting in shell - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bash, another option can be converting `DSLSTATE` into an associative array. After that, it will be easier to get a value based on a key:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DSLSTATE='NewEnable 1
NewStatus Up
NewDataPath Fast
NewUpstreamCurrRate 21598
NewDownstreamCurrRate 170788
NewUpstreamMaxRate 25692
NewDownstreamMaxRate 170788
NewUpstreamNoiseMargin 90
NewDownstreamNoiseMargin 60
NewUpstreamAttenuation 150
NewDownstreamAttenuation 170
NewATURVendor 41564d00
NewATURCountry 0400
NewUpstreamPower 486
NewDownstreamPower 514'

declare -A kv

while read k v; do
    kv[$k]=$v
done <<< $DSLSTATE

echo "NewDownstreamPower: ${kv[NewDownstreamPower]}"
```

The code above will result in:

```yaml
NewDownstreamPower: 514
```